# How to disable gutemberg css only if classic editor is activated?

Tags: php, css, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to delete the css of gutenberg on wordpress only when the Classic Editor plugin is active.

This is the code I use to turn it off, but I'd like to make it dependent on the plugin

```
function remove_block_css(){
wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_block_css', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your add_action call inside a conditional checking for the existence of the Classic Editor class:
`if ( class_exists( 'Classic_Editor' ) ) {}` or you can have a look at: `is_plugin_active` in the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active